# Characterization of contact vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, contact-geometry

Let $H$ be a subbundle of the tangent bundle $TM$ of a smooth manifold $M$.
A vector field $K$ on $M$ is *contact* if its flow $\Phi_K^t$ preserves $H$.

I found in many references the following characterization:

> A vector field $K$ is contact if and only if $[K,V]\in \Gamma(H)$ for all $V\in\Gamma(H)$.

I use the notation $\Gamma(H)$ to denote the smooth sections of $H$.
Question: what is the proof? I am okay with one direction, namely that a contact vector field satisfies the above condition.
The other direction is not clear: Suppose $K$ is a vector field such that $[K,V]\in \Gamma(H)$ for all $V\in\Gamma(H)$: why is it contact?

A first attempt brought me to the following:
Let $V\in\Gamma(H)$ and let's prove that the push forward

$$
c(t) := (\Phi_K^{-t})_*V\in\Gamma(H)
$$

for all $t$ (assuming $K$ is complete; the "-t" is for beauty).
The derivation in $t$ gives:

$$
c'(t) 
= \frac{d}{dh}|_{h=0} (\Phi_K^{-t-h})_*V 
= (\Phi_K^{-t})_* ( \frac{d}{dh}|_{h=0} (\Phi_K^{-h})_*V) 
= (\Phi_K^{-t})_* ( [K,V] ) .
$$

So, if $t=0$, then $c'(0)\in \Gamma(H)$.
But, what happens when $t$ is not zero?

Notes:

1. the above computation gives in fact $c'(t) = [K,c(t)]$, if it is useful.
2. in the (few) proofs that I found of this characterization, they usually write $c'(t) = [K,V]$, which is wrong. See for instance page 8 in
   https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.966/2014SP/notes.pdf

Comment: Look at my Introduction to Exterior Differential Systems, and the discussion of bundled systems, where you can find the details of a proof for vector subbundles of the cotangent bundle, which has an isomorphic proof for vector subbundles of the tangent bundle.